# Transiting through Rome Italy

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, layovers

I bought this ticket at a  short notice and I have to leave on Saturday from Mumbai to NY. I have a 4 hour layover in Rome. With a US permanent resident Green Card and an Indian passport do  I still need to have any kind of short term visa from Italy or I can transit  effortlessly . I check the VFS website for Mumbai India but haven't had luck finding any kind of clarification on this

Comment: It is far too exhaustive and also very vague and it does not specifically clarify on the case with Italy. My concern is only 4 hours in Rome and not interested in visiting the European Union all knowing EU visa laws

Comment: Last I checked Rome was still in Italy and Italy was part of Schengen aquis so rules laid out in that answer still apply.

Comment: there are commonalities and there are places where things will differ from country to country so I would like to know specifically in short what it  comes to for 4 hours are staying in Rome without reading through a pile full of instruction manual